# Differences between remote debugger and created package (WinRT Store App)

Tags: debugging, crash, windows-runtime, remote-debugging, tablet-pc

I am developing an application for a mobile device (namely WinRT Tablet). I have a x86 test device that I installed the created app package on. However, it crashes when I try to start it. I figured I would run it through a remote debugger in order to see what is wrong as it runs in both the simulator and local host without any trouble. However, when I run it through the remote debugger, it runs fine on the device as well.

This is causing me a headache as it I have no idea how I can debug this when it runs splendidly through the remote debugger. I have a hunch that it has something to do with the connectivity in the app as it has ran on the device (installed from the packages) before I had this functionality in. I have added capabilities to the package. Does the remote debugger offer the app another access to network that bypasses the default (that might or might not be causing the issues) option?

Any ideas on how to debug this? Does WinRT generate some log on ran apps somewhere? I have no idea how to approach this problem.

Comment: Is it a C++ app or uses some C++ component?

Comment: Maybe you could add some kind of logging into locale storage to see how far it gets and where it crashes. Are you creating the package for debug build? Is the problem still there in release build?

Comment: Please let me know if you are using any third party dll and if every line of code is completely exception handled